# C concepts on arrays

Tags: c, arrays, output

```
int main(){

    int arr[2]={30,40};
    printf("%dn",i[arr]);
    return 0;
}
```

I found this question in an examination and the given solution is
40

But I think it should give an error since i is undefined.
Or, may be I am missing something.
Please explain me how 40 is the correct answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` has be defined otherwise this won't compile, if `i` has the value `1` then that output makes sense. Alternatively, if `i` was really `1` that would also work.

Comment: `printf` is undefined too ...

Comment: This is an OCR error. It should be 1, not i.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Comment: Yes @dyp , if int i = 1, then i is defined now so value of 1[arr]= arr[1] is 40

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, the code is wrong. Likely, it is a typo, and the intent was either to define `i` or to use `1[arr]`.

Comment: Thanks eric for your response. I agree with you. May be it was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it is an error, since `i` is not defined.

Also, probably the intention of the exercise is to take advantage of the fact that in **C**, you can write `v[ i ]` in order to access the #*i* element of a vector *v*, or `i[ v ]`.

Both forms are equivalent.Since `v[ i ]` is translated as `*( v + i )`, there is actually not any difference between that and `*( i + v )`, which is what `i[ v ]` is translated for. This is not a common use, but is nonetheless valid.

[Arrays in C, from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Arrays)

In this specific example, `1[arr]` would return the expected answer.

I just wonder why they chose 40 instead of 42.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In C `array[index] = *(array + index) = *(index + array) = index[array]`. Assuming `i` to be `1` (otherwise behavior is undefined), `1[arr]` is equivalent to `arr[1]` and it contains value `40`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is probably supposed to be given as 1, either in the spoken part of the examination, or in a part that is missing. As written, the question is of course inapplicable since it doesn't compile.

The real point of the question is to test whether the applicant understands that `array[index]` is equivalent to `index[array]` and (presumably) why.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, let's see shall we...

```
matilda:~ jeremyp$ cat > foo.c
int main(){

    int arr[2]={30,40};
    printf("%dn",i[arr]);
    return 0;
}
matilda:~ jeremyp$ cc foo.c
foo.c:4:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'
    printf("%dn",i[arr]);
    ^
foo.c:4:5: note: please include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'printf'
foo.c:4:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    printf("%dn",i[arr]);
                 ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Yes indeed, `i` is undefined.  You either need

```
int i = 1;
```

before that statement or it isn't an `i`, it's a `1`.  Let's try that...

```
matilda:~ jeremyp$ cat >foo.c
#include <stdio.h> // Stops the warning
int main(){

    int arr[2]={30,40};
    printf("%d\n",1[arr]); // Also added a \ so we get a line feed.
    return 0;
}
matilda:~ jeremyp$ cc foo.c
matilda:~ jeremyp$ ./a.out
40
```

That works now.